# How to install pdo_sqlsrv php extension on openSUSE leap 15

Tags: php, opensuse

I have been following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017#installing-the-drivers-on-suse-12

and countless of google search forum results for hours with no results. I have installed:

1. PHP 7.2,
2. Apache 2.4
3. Mssql server

on my openSUSE machine. 
I am connecting to the mssql database through laravel but getting driver not found error. Can someone please help

*UPDATE:*

For anyone having the same problem, Microsoft tutorial is based on openSUSE server variant. I managed to fiddle around with the [URL](https://packages.microsoft.com/config/opensuse/)

and it seems that microsoft only supports up to leap 42.3.

Seems like i will be installing to docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft finally released the opensuse 15 drivers and I installed them. However, I'm
sticking to docker.